# Which Variable Stores Nginx Source Port Toward Upstream

Tags: nginx

I'd like to read the source port, i.e. Nginx' own source port (as client) used to communicate with upstream.

Could not find it in the documentation, but would make send to have it.

Comment: If you really need this, the upstream should log it. But you probably don't need this.

Comment: @MichaelHampton is right.  You probably don't need this.

Comment: I **need** it. That's why I post this question.

Comment: Maybe if you explain why you feel you need it we can better answer your question?

Comment: Well, to debug network issues on the upstream side. But what is the difference, I mean is this value exposable or not?

Comment: @TzuryBarYochay were you able to find this value ? I need it, to be able to debug the outgoing requests on my checkpoint firewall. I wasn't able to find any variable in nginx or function in openresty which exposes this.